# How to pass data into generics?

Tags: c#, generics

Trying to pass fields of T-object "Item01" into generic "Item01Holder" without creating an instance of T-object, so generic could use info from T-object in constructor. Is it even possible?

p.s. now I'm passing static members of "Item01" into generic constructor, but it's not the best way 'cause requires a lot of code to write.

```
    static class Program
{
    private static string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\data\\Units\\A200--PROJECTS\\BA\\Develop\\develop.accdb";
    public static OleDbConnection main_connection;

    static void Main()
    {
        main_connection = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
        main_connection.Open();

    }
}

public class Item01
{
    public static string name { get { return "x"; } }
    public static string name2 = "";
}

public class Item01Holder<T> where T : Item01, new()
{
    public Item01Holder(string _name)
    {
       
       // T.name or T.name2 -- how to get it here?
    }
}
```

Comment: C# sadly does not provide a way to specify a type constraint for a constructor with parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At least, I couldn't find a way to pass data from T-object into generic constructor without creating instance of T.
Thus I do `T t = new T();`  and use virtual -- override declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Since `name1` and `name2` are static field that belong to `Item01` you just reference this type

```
public class Item01
{
    public static string name { get { return "x"; } }
    public static string name2 = "";
}

public class Item01Holder<T> where T : Item01, new()
{
    public Item01Holder(string _name)
    {
       Item01.name2 = _name;
       var x = Item01.name1;
    }
}
```